# Why does my 3D object not show in my Unity canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a canvas to show InformationText on the screen. This works perfectly fine. However, when I try to put a 3D object in my canvas, it doesn't show. Can somebody tell me why?

I'm using Unity 2019.2.12f1

My canvas:
[image: Canvas]

My Main Camera:
[image: Main Camera]

My MarkerModel
[image: MarkerModel]

The Game
[image: Gamescreen]

Comment: Because canvases are not meant to do that. Canvas = UI

Comment: Is there a way to work around that?

Answer (score 0):

I added a camera to my 3D-object. This fixed the problem for me!

Comment: What. There is no way that that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Set canvas to world space

[image: Canvas option]

and put canvas near your 3D object and move camera to make object and canvas visible

[image: Scene view] [image: Gameview]

Comment: Actually, a `scree space (Camera)` canvas would probably be better.